# If $X \sim \mathcal{P}(u)$, show that $S=(-1)^X$ is the UMVUE of $e^{2u}$

Tags: self-study, unbiased-estimator, estimators

> If $X \sim \mathcal{P}(u)$, show that $S=(-1)^X$ is the UMVUE of
>   $e^{2u}$.

I can't figure this out, finding UMVUE always confuses me. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What does "$\mathcal{P}(u)$" mean?

Comment: @whuber I believe he refers to the Poisson distribution with mean $u$, at least I took it as such.

Answer (score 2):

-What is the sufficient statistic for one observation coming from a Poisson distribution?

-Is your estimator unbiased?

-Is it a function of the sufficient statistic?

-Is the family of that sufficient statistic complete?

If you find the sufficient statistic and also find that the answer to the following three questions is affirmative, then you are done.